# How to get date in Thursday, September 26, 2013 format?

Tags: php, date

I want to get date in following format **Thursday, September 26, 2013.**

The name of day should be full like Monday not like Mon and same for the month format.

How to get this format?

Comment: Just look out: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.date.php

Comment: There's a whole bunch of ways to do this. What have you tried already? How close did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this like following way

```
$mydate=getdate(date("U"));
echo "$mydate[weekday], $mydate[month] $mydate[mday], $mydate[year]";
```

OR

```
$today = date(DATE_RFC822);
echo date('l,F d,Y',strtotime($today));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use php date function as below.

```
echo date('l,F d,Y',strtotime($date));
```

<kbd>[**Date Format**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)</kbd>